# how to put Simple slider image inside google maps infowindow?

Tags: google-maps, slider, infowindow

I'am trying to display multiple image in a single infowindows. there is 3 image. i just want to make a slider work in info window google maps. but may be i lost the main idea. i try to use some of jquery slider and javascript slider, but still not work, the image not display and in other case is only work for the first click infowindows.

i think some missing, can somebody help me to the right direction of this case. i try to search an example, but the result is still nothing.

many thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far? Or a link to your page if it's live.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XX6R4/ sorry for late answer your comment. can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the event name you should be listening for in the `addListener` call where you initiate the slider:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, function(){ /*..initiate anythingslider..*/ });
```

It should listen for the `content_changed` event on the `infoWindow`, so it should look like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'content_changed', function(){ /*..initiate anythingslider..*/ });
```

Comment: when you ran this with the code in your post did it work?